# UP and Down Arrow Icons functionality not working in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Basically I need to show and Hide the div , Up and Down Arrow Icons should change accordingly. As of Now only UP arrow Icon is working and displaying the div , but when i try to hide the div, it is not working....I did like this and its not working , What wrong in my code? Can Anyone help me in this?

Here is my Code

```
const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false); 

<div onClick={() => setExpand(true)}> 
    Accordion 
    <i className={`fas fa-chevron-up ${!expand ? 'fas fa-chevron-down' : ''}`}></i>
</div>
{expand && <div className="Accordion-Section"></div>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `className` like this

```js
<div onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}> 
    Accordion 
    <i className={`fas ${expand ? 'fa-chevron-up' : 'fa-chevron-down'}`} />
</div>
{expand && <div className="Accordion-Section"></div>}
```

Comment: Icon is getting changed but Div content is not getting hidden...Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: The accordion section div? It should be hidden when expand is false

Answer (score 1):

The click handler is setting the state `true` everytime.

You should change it to `<div onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}>`.

Answer (score 0):

you should change "i" tag to this:

> <i className={`${!expand ? "fas fa-chevron-down" : "fas fa-chevron-up"}`}>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).